# Redundant function . How to return response in another way?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
function redundantFunc(){
        let response: SignInResponse = {
            user: user,
            account: account,
            company: company
        };
        return response;
}
```

It says me that `response` value is redundant. How to return it in another way? ?

Answer (score 2):

You can just type the return value of your function:

```
function redundantFunc(): SignInResponse {
    return {
        user: user,
        account: account,
        company: company
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

simply return it, no need of declaring and assigning it to a variable

```
function redundantFunc(): SignInResponse {
    return {
        user: user,
        account: account,
        company: company
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Return object with SignInResponse as its property.

```
function redundantFunc(){
    return {
      SignInResponse:{
        user: user,
        account: account,
        company: company
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're really trying to wait down redundant code you can use ES6 object literals:

```js
let company = "BigCo", account = "test account", user = "mark"

const redundantFunc = () => ({response: {user, account, company}})

console.log(redundantFunc())
```